# How to disregard a repetitive chain?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, indexing

I want my code to disregard a repetitive chain in the output but I don't know where to put the code.

This is my code:

```
alphabet = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]

def agent(host, receiver):
    # Check the length of host and receiver
    if len(host) == 4:
        if len(receiver) == 4:
            # Check if host and receiver have valid IDs (capital letters)
            if host[0] in alphabet and host[1] in alphabet and host[2] in alphabet and host[3] in alphabet:
                if receiver[0] in alphabet and receiver[1] in alphabet and receiver[2] in alphabet and receiver[3] in alphabet:
                    final_chain = [host]
                    receiver_index_1 = alphabet.index(receiver[0])
                    # Call for_loop_sort for each position in the host and receiver
                    chain_1 = for_loop_sort(host, receiver, receiver_index_1) + host[1:]
                    final_chain.append(chain_1)
                    receiver_index_2 = alphabet.index(receiver[1])
                    chain_2 = receiver[0] + for_loop_sort(host, receiver, receiver_index_2) + host[2:]
                    final_chain.append(chain_2)
                    receiver_index_3 = alphabet.index(receiver[2])
                    chain_3 = receiver[0] + receiver[1] + for_loop_sort(host, receiver, receiver_index_3) + host[3:]
                    final_chain.append(chain_3)
                    receiver_index_4 = alphabet.index(receiver[3])
                    chain_4 = receiver[0] + receiver[1] + receiver[2] + for_loop_sort(host, receiver, receiver_index_4)
                    final_chain.append(chain_4)
                    return final_chain
                else:
                    return "Error, receiver agent has an invalid ID; agent should only have capital letters"
            else:
                return "Error, host agent has an invalid ID; agent should only have capital letters"
        else:
            return "Error, receiver agent has an invalid ID; agent should only have 4 capital letters."
    else:
        return "Error, host agent has an invalid ID; agent should only have 4 capital letters."

def for_loop_sort(host, receiver, receiver_index):
    # Iterate through the alphabet list
    for index in range(len(alphabet)):
        # Check if the current index matches the receiver_index
        if index == receiver_index:
            return alphabet[index]

host = "CORE"
receivers = ["MBID", "BRKS", "JKIC", "MRRY", "BTLR",
             "ADBY", "DRNT", "IRVN", "HRDN", "DNCN",
             "BRNT", "PAUL", "WRTH", "JNSN", "LLRD",
             "BIRD", "JRDN", "PIPN", "EWNG", "BRKL",
             "OLJW", "CRRY", "TMPS", "TTUM", "GRNT"]

listchain = []
w = {}
count = 0

for receiver in receivers:
    count += 1
    final_chain = agent(host, receiver)
    final_chain_name = f"R2P{count}"
    final_chain.insert(0, final_chain_name)

    # Check if the chain is already present in listchain
    if final_chain[2:] not in [chain[2:] for chain in listchain]:
        listchain.append(final_chain)

        chain_1_weight = 40
        chain_2_weight = 30
        chain_3_weight = 20
        chain_4_weight = 10

        if final_chain[2] in w.keys():
            chain_1_weight += w[final_chain[2]]
        if final_chain[3] in w.keys():
            chain_2_weight += w[final_chain[3]]
        if final_chain[4] in w.keys():
            chain_3_weight += w[final_chain[4]]
        if final_chain[5] in w.keys():
            chain_4_weight += w[final_chain[5]]

        w[final_chain[2]] = chain_1_weight
        w[final_chain[3]] = chain_2_weight
        w[final_chain[4]] = chain_3_weight
        w[final_chain[5]] = chain_4_weight

for chain in listchain:
    print(f"{chain[0]}: {chain[2]} {w[chain[2]]} -> {chain[3]} {w[chain[3]]} -> {chain[4]} {w[chain[4]]} -> {chain[5]}
```

and this is the output

```
R2P1: MORE 80 -> MBRE 30 -> MBIE 20 -> MBID 10
R2P2: BORE 200 -> BRRE 90 -> BRKE 40 -> BRKS 10
R2P3: JORE 120 -> JKRE 30 -> JKIE 20 -> JKIC 10
R2P4: MORE 80 -> MRRE 20 -> MRRE 20 -> MRRY 10
R2P5: BORE 200 -> BTRE 30 -> BTLE 20 -> BTLR 10
R2P6: AORE 40 -> ADRE 30 -> ADBE 20 -> ADBY 10
R2P7: DORE 80 -> DRRE 30 -> DRNE 20 -> DRNT 10
R2P8: IORE 40 -> IRRE 30 -> IRVE 20 -> IRVN 10
R2P9: HORE 40 -> HRRE 30 -> HRDE 20 -> HRDN 10
R2P10: DORE 80 -> DNRE 30 -> DNCE 20 -> DNCN 10
R2P11: BORE 200 -> BRRE 90 -> BRNE 20 -> BRNT 10
R2P12: PORE 80 -> PARE 30 -> PAUE 20 -> PAUL 10
R2P13: WORE 40 -> WRRE 30 -> WRTE 20 -> WRTH 10
R2P14: JORE 120 -> JNRE 30 -> JNSE 20 -> JNSN 10
R2P15: LORE 40 -> LLRE 20 -> LLRE 20 -> LLRD 10
R2P16: BORE 200 -> BIRE 20 -> BIRE 20 -> BIRD 10
R2P17: JORE 120 -> JRRE 30 -> JRDE 20 -> JRDN 10
R2P18: PORE 80 -> PIRE 30 -> PIPE 20 -> PIPN 10
R2P19: EORE 40 -> EWRE 30 -> EWNE 20 -> EWNG 10
R2P20: BORE 200 -> BRRE 90 -> BRKE 40 -> BRKL 10
R2P21: OORE 40 -> OLRE 30 -> OLJE 20 -> OLJW 10
R2P22: CORE 40 -> CRRE 20 -> CRRE 20 -> CRRY 10
R2P23: TORE 80 -> TMRE 30 -> TMPE 20 -> TMPS 10
R2P24: TORE 80 -> TTRE 30 -> TTUE 20 -> TTUM 10
R2P25: GORE 40 -> GRRE 30 -> GRNE 20 -> GRNT 10
```

But I want my output to be like this:

```
R2P1: MORE 80 -> MBRE 30 -> MBIE 20 -> MBID 10
R2P2: BORE 200 -> BRRE 90 -> BRKE 40 -> BRKS 10
R2P3: JORE 120 -> JKRE 30 -> JKIE 20 -> JKIC 10
R2P4: MORE 80 -> MRRE 30 -> MRRY 10
R2P5: BORE 200 -> BTRE 30 -> BTLE 20 -> BTLR 10
R2P6: AORE 40 -> ADRE 30 -> ADBE 20 -> ADBY 10
R2P7: DORE 80 -> DRRE 30 -> DRNE 20 -> DRNT 10
R2P8: IORE 40 -> IRRE 30 -> IRVE 20 -> IRVN 10
R2P9: HORE 40 -> HRRE 30 -> HRDE 20 -> HRDN 10
R2P10: DORE 80 -> DNRE 30 -> DNCE 20 -> DNCN 10
R2P11: BORE 200 -> BRRE 90 -> BRNE 20 -> BRNT 10
R2P12: PORE 80 -> PARE 30 -> PAUE 20 -> PAUL 10
R2P13: WORE 40 -> WRRE 30 -> WRTE 20 -> WRTH 10
R2P14: JORE 120 -> JNRE 30 -> JNSE 20 -> JNSN 10
R2P15: LORE 40 -> LLRE 30 -> LLRD 10
R2P16: BORE 200 -> BIRE 30 -> BIRD 10
R2P17: JORE 120 -> JRRE 30 -> JRDE 20 -> JRDN 10
R2P18: PORE 80 -> PIRE 30 -> PIPE 20 -> PIPN 10
R2P19: EORE 40 -> EWRE 30 -> EWNE 20 -> EWNG 10
R2P20: BORE 200 -> BRRE 90 -> BRKE 40 -> BRKL 10
R2P21: OORE 40 -> OLRE 30 -> OLJE 20 -> OLJW 10
R2P22: CRRE 40  -> CRRY 10
R2P23: TORE 80 -> TMRE 30 -> TMPE 20 -> TMPS 10
R2P24: TORE 80 -> TTRE 30 -> TTUE 20 -> TTUM 10
R2P25: GORE 40 -> GRRE 30 -> GRNE 20 -> GRNT 10
```

You can see that there are shorter paths because the sorted chain was repeating. I want to disregard it and the fixed weights will remain depending on chain weight assigned.

Note that chain[1] (in line "for chain in listchains") is the host, meaning its the chain CORE. So it has no weight.

I also want to disregard any chain that is repetitive with the host.

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: What, exactly, is for_loop_sort() trying to do? There's no sorting. The first two parameters are not used. Functionally, as currently written, it could just be *return alphabet[receiver_index]*

Comment: first thing to do I think is, while creating the final chain with the agent function. each time you add a chain to the final chain list check if the chain already exist there. `if chain_2 not in final_chain: final_chain.append(chain_2)`.

Comment: @Nesi is it okay if you could show me the code?

Comment: @DarkKnight the function finds the corresponding letter in the alphabet list based on the given receiver_index.

Comment: @mamab In which case *return alphabet[receiver_index]* will suffice. There's no need for any kind of loop

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check if the chain already exist in your list or not. I will show you how to remove duplicate chains from the list. But you need to modify the rest of your code accordingly.

```
alphabet = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]

def agent(host, receiver):
    # Check the length of host and receiver
    if len(host) == 4:
        if len(receiver) == 4:
            # Check if host and receiver have valid IDs (capital letters)
            if host[0] in alphabet and host[1] in alphabet and host[2] in alphabet and host[3] in alphabet:
                if receiver[0] in alphabet and receiver[1] in alphabet and receiver[2] in alphabet and receiver[3] in alphabet:
                    final_chain = [host]
                    receiver_index_1 = alphabet.index(receiver[0])
                    # Call for_loop_sort for each position in the host and receiver
                    chain_1 = for_loop_sort(host, receiver, receiver_index_1) + host[1:]
                    final_chain.append(chain_1)
                    receiver_index_2 = alphabet.index(receiver[1])
                    chain_2 = receiver[0] + for_loop_sort(host, receiver, receiver_index_2) + host[2:]

                    # add chain if its not in final chain.
                    if chain_2 not in final_chain:
                        final_chain.append(chain_2)
                    receiver_index_3 = alphabet.index(receiver[2])
                    chain_3 = receiver[0] + receiver[1] + for_loop_sort(host, receiver, receiver_index_3) + host[3:]

                    # add chain if its not in final chain.
                    if chain_3 not in final_chain:
                        final_chain.append(chain_3)
                    receiver_index_4 = alphabet.index(receiver[3])
                    chain_4 = receiver[0] + receiver[1] + receiver[2] + for_loop_sort(host, receiver, receiver_index_4)

                    # add chain if its not in final chain.
                    if chain_4 not in final_chain:
                        final_chain.append(chain_4)
                    return final_chain
                else:
                    return "Error, receiver agent has an invalid ID; agent should only have capital letters"
            else:
                return "Error, host agent has an invalid ID; agent should only have capital letters"
        else:
            return "Error, receiver agent has an invalid ID; agent should only have 4 capital letters."
    else:
        return "Error, host agent has an invalid ID; agent should only have 4 capital letters."

def for_loop_sort(host, receiver, receiver_index):
    # Iterate through the alphabet list
    for index in range(len(alphabet)):
        # Check if the current index matches the receiver_index
        if index == receiver_index:
            return alphabet[index]

host = "CORE"
receivers = ["MBID", "BRKS", "JKIC", "MRRY", "BTLR",
             "ADBY", "DRNT", "IRVN", "HRDN", "DNCN",
             "BRNT", "PAUL", "WRTH", "JNSN", "LLRD",
             "BIRD", "JRDN", "PIPN", "EWNG", "BRKL",
             "OLJW", "CRRY", "TMPS", "TTUM", "GRNT"]

listchain = []
w = {}
count = 0

for receiver in receivers:
    count += 1
    final_chain = agent(host, receiver)
    print(final_chain)

# Now you can modify the rest of the code to get what you want.
```

Comment: I forgot to add that to disregard the chain if it is the same as the host which is "CORE". My bad

Comment: Also, how can I use my code where I assign the weights if the there's an list index out of range error?

Answer (score 0):

the code had some really useless stuff so i removed those and cleaned up a little but the problem was weight distribution with if and stuff and the data duplication at final_chain as [Nesi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5422850/nesi) said so this is how the code goes:

```
def agent(host, receiver):
    # Check the length of host and receiver
    if len(host) != 4:
        return "Error, host agent has an invalid ID; agent should only have 4 capital letters."
    if len(receiver) != 4:
        return "Error, receiver agent has an invalid ID; agent should only have 4 capital letters."
    
    # Check if host and receiver have valid IDs (capital letters)
    if not all((i.isupper()) for i in host):
        return "Error, host agent has an invalid ID; agent should only have capital letters"
    if not all((i.isupper()) for i in receiver):
            return "Error, receiver agent has an invalid ID; agent should only have capital letters"

    final_chain = [host]

    for i in range(4):
        chain = receiver[:i+1] + host[i+1:]
        if chain == final_chain[-1]:
            continue
        final_chain.append(chain)
    return final_chain
        
        

host = "CORE"
receivers = ["MBID", "BRKS", "JKIC", "MRRY", "BTLR",
             "ADBY", "DRNT", "IRVN", "HRDN", "DNCN",
             "BRNT", "PAUL", "WRTH", "JNSN", "LLRD",
             "BIRD", "JRDN", "PIPN", "EWNG", "BRKL",
             "OLJW", "CRRY", "TMPS", "TTUM", "GRNT"]

listchain = []
w = {}
count = 0

for receiver in receivers:
    count += 1
    final_chain = agent(host, receiver)
    final_chain_name = f"R2P{count}"
    final_chain.insert(0, final_chain_name)

    # Check if the chain is already present in listchain
    if final_chain[2:] not in [chain[2:] for chain in listchain]:
        listchain.append(final_chain)

        ## improtent part

        
        chain_weights = [40, 30, 20, 10]
        c = 0
        for i in final_chain[2:]:
            w[i] = chain_weights[c] + w.get(i, 0)
            c += 1
        


for chain in listchain:
    print(f"{chain[0]}:", end="")
    for i in chain[2: -1]:
        print(f" {i} {w[i]}", end=" ->")
    print(f" {chain[-1]} {w[chain[-1]]}")
```

## update:

just realized what you want is not this one according your expected output so you shouldn't delete multiplied chains but instead just change the output like:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
alphabet = [i for i in ascii_uppercase]


def agent(host, receiver):
    # Check the length of host and receiver
    if len(host) != 4:
        return "Error, host agent has an invalid ID; agent should only have 4 capital letters."
    if len(receiver) != 4:
        return "Error, receiver agent has an invalid ID; agent should only have 4 capital letters."
    
    # Check if host and receiver have valid IDs (capital letters)
    if not all((i.isupper()) for i in host):
        return "Error, host agent has an invalid ID; agent should only have capital letters"
    if not all((i.isupper()) for i in receiver):
            return "Error, receiver agent has an invalid ID; agent should only have capital letters"

    final_chain = [host]

    for i in range(4):
        chain = receiver[:i+1] + host[i+1:]
        if chain == host:
            continue
        final_chain.append(chain)
    return final_chain
        
        

host = "CORE"
receivers = ["MBID", "BRKS", "JKIC", "MRRY", "BTLR",
             "ADBY", "DRNT", "IRVN", "HRDN", "DNCN",
             "BRNT", "PAUL", "WRTH", "JNSN", "LLRD",
             "BIRD", "JRDN", "PIPN", "EWNG", "BRKL",
             "OLJW", "CRRY", "TMPS", "TTUM", "GRNT"]

listchain = []
w = {}
count = 0

for receiver in receivers:
    count += 1
    final_chain = agent(host, receiver)
    final_chain_name = f"R2P{count}"
    final_chain.insert(0, final_chain_name)

    # Check if the chain is already present in listchain
    if final_chain[2:] not in [chain[2:] for chain in listchain]:
        listchain.append(final_chain)

        ## improtent part

        chain_1_weight = 40
        chain_2_weight = 30
        chain_3_weight = 20
        chain_4_weight = 10 

        try:
            w[final_chain[2]] = chain_1_weight + w.get(final_chain[2], 0)
            w[final_chain[3]] = chain_2_weight*(final_chain[3] != final_chain[2]) + w.get(final_chain[3], 0)
            w[final_chain[4]] = chain_3_weight*(final_chain[4] != final_chain[3]) + w.get(final_chain[4], 0)
            w[final_chain[5]] = chain_4_weight*(final_chain[5] != final_chain[4]) + w.get(final_chain[5], 0)
        except:
            pass


for chain in listchain:
    print(f"{chain[0]}:", end="")
    c = None
    for i in chain[2: -1]:
        if i != c:
            print(f" {i} {w[i]}", end=" ->")
        c = i
    print(f" {chain[-1]} {w[chain[-1]]}")
```

Comment: Instead of *if not all((i.isupper()) for i in host):* how about *if not host.isupper():*

Comment: that is so wise i just got embarrassed

Comment: I just noticed the wrong weight in some path. The weight of the agents in the receivers list should be 10. R2P4, R2P15, R2P16, and R2P22 have incorrect weights on the last chain. The last chain should be fixed at 10. I'm sorry for the confusion.